# What is the reason behind camel exclusion from Spring Boot >= 2.7.0 in start.spring.io

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

In start.spring.io, when Spring Boot 2.7.1 is selected it reports that Apache Camel "Requires Spring Boot >= 2.0.0.M1 and < 2.7.0-M1" (see screenshot below).

[image]

Is there a specific reason for this or where can I find more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Camel team have not yet indicated that `camel-spring-boot-starter` supports Spring Boot 2.7. Until they're ready to support 2.7, the combination is disabled. Support for Spring Boot 2.7 seems to be [part of Camel 3.18](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-18153) which, at the time of writing, has not been released.